# Floating point multiplication results in infinity even though rounding to nearest

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding, infinity, rounding-error

Consider the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <fenv.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    fesetround(FE_TONEAREST);
    double a = 0x1.efc7f0001p+376;
    double b = -0x1.0fdfdp+961;
    double c = a*b;
    cout << a << " "<< b << " " << c << endl;
}
```

The output that I see is

```
2.98077e+113 -2.06992e+289 -inf
```

I do not understand why `c` is infinity. My understanding is that whatever the smallest non-infinity floating point value is, it should be closer to the actual value of `a*b` than `-inf` as the minimum non-infinity floating point number is finite and any finite number is closer to any other finite number than negative infinity. Why is infinity outputted here?

This was run on 64bit x86 and the assembly uses SSE instructions. It was compiled with -O0 and happens both with clang and gcc.

The result is the minimum finite floating point if the round towards zero mode is used for floating points. I conclude that the issue is rounding related.

Comment: Those numbers do seem to be beyond the limit of what a `double` can reasonably handle.

Comment: Check the [ranges available](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) for different floating-point types. Maybe you need a 128-bit float, or `long double` in C++ parlance.

Comment: I think there is a difference between rounding and overflow behavior (I don't know the standard by heart, though ...)

Comment: I understand that double cannot contain any value close to the mathematically correct one. However, this does not change the error compared to the floating point min is smaller than compared to negative infinity. The computed result is not the nearest representable floating point.

Comment: @chtz The issue goes away when I put the floating points into round towards zero mode. I conclude that this is rounding related

Comment: @HeygardFlisch You should add that last comment to the actual question. I think it's important.

Comment: I'm sort of guessing, here, but the issue probably stems from the fact that comparing anything to a `NaN` value returns unordered: so, if we take `underflow` to represent the intermediate (calculated) value, then no comparisons can distinguish whether `inf` or `DBL_MIN` is closer to `underflow`.

Comment: Also (again, I'm not sure here) but I guess `inf` *could* be considered as a "representable value". But this is wild speculation.

Comment: Whether inf is representable or not does not impact it‘s distance to other values.

Comment: I think you're confusing the mathematical/real-world concept of infinity with the IEEE-754/computer-float value that is called "infinity". It is a representation; nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you note (when using the `FE_TONEAREST` rounding mode) conforms to the IEEE-754 (or the equivalent ISO/IEC/IEEE 60559:2011) Standard. (Your examples imply that your platform uses IEEE-754 representation, as many – if not most – platforms do, these days.)

From [this Wikipedia page, footnote #18](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754#cite_note-22), which cites IEEE-754 §4.3.1, dealing with the "rounding to nearest" modes:

> In the following two rounding-direction attributes, an infinitely
> precise result with magnitude at least
> **b<sup>emax</sup>(b-½b<sup>(1-p)</sup>)** shall round to **∞** (infinity) with no change in sign.

The 'infinitely precise' result of your `a * b` calculation does, indeed, have a magnitude greater than the specified value, so the rounding is Standard-conformant.

---

I can't find a similar IEEE-754 citation for the "round-towards-zero" mode, but [this GNU libc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html) has this to say:

> Round toward zero.
>  All results are rounded to the largest
> representable value whose magnitude is less than that of the result.
> In other words, if the result is negative it is rounded up; if it is
> positive, it is rounded down.

So, again, when using that mode, rounding to `-DBL_MAX` is appropriate/conformant.

Comment: Thanks, it seems like „rounding to nearest“ is simply not defined to always round to nearest.

Comment: @HeygardFlisch: Rounding to nearest is defined to always round to nearest, per IEEE 754-2019 4.3. The result is not caused by rounding; it is caused by the default result of an overflow exception. In other words, the operation did not “round to nearest” to get infinity. It rounded to nearest, determined that would not fit in the format, generated an overflow exception, and, because overflow exceptions are masked (do not generate an interrupt/trap), delivered a default result.

Answer (score 5):

Rounding is not the primary issue here. The infinite result is caused by overflow.

This answer follows the rules in IEEE 754-2019. The real-number-arithmetic product of 1.EFC7F0001<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>376</sup> and −1.0FDFD<sub>961</sub>•2<sup>16</sup> is around −1.07430C8649FEFE8<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>1335</sup>. In normal conditions, floating-point arithmetic produces a result “as if it first produced an intermediate result correct to infinite precision and with unbounded range, and then rounded that result…” (IEEE 754-2019 4.3). However, we do not have normal conditions. IEEE 754-2019 7.4 says:

> The overflow exception shall be signaled if and only if the destination format’s largest finite number is exceeded in magnitude by what would have been the rounded floating-point result (see 4) were the exponent range unbounded…

In other words, if we rounded the result as if we could have any exponent (so we are just rounding the significand), the result would be −1.07430C8649FF+964<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>1338</sup>. But the magnitude of that exceeds the largest finite number that `double` can represent, ±1.FFFFFFFFFFFFF<sub>16</sub>•2<sup>1023</sup>. Therefore, an overflow exception is signaled, and, since you do not catch the exception, a default result is delivered:

> … The default result shall be determined by the rounding-direction attribute and the sign of the intermediate result as follows:
>
> a) roundTiesToEven and roundTiesToAway carry all overflows to ∞ with the sign of the intermediate result…